# Install clang 3.4 on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, clang, visual-studio-2015

The final release of Visual Studio 2015 uses clang 3.6.

On my projects, I use more libraries that was compiled with clang 3.4.
Is there a way to install clang 3.4 on Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: You can write your own msbuild file and build it manually, but Visual Studio works with their own compiler.

Comment: @Blindy Thanks! Could you suggest me a tutorial to write my msbuild file?